# How to get the project machine in treeline

Tags: sails.js, treeline

In [treeline](https://treeline.io/) you have a project machine which contains your custom machines and functions like create user.

I would like to know if there is a variable or easy way to retrieve the project machine dir name  (e.g. "_project_1234_0.0.1") part.

It is my intention to create a user (and other models) from a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there was no answer to my question I found some time to get this sorted.

Place the following in

> config/bootstrap.js

```
// Set Treeline machine
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('lodash');

// Get all machine directories and loop through them
var machines = fs.readdirSync('api/machines/');
_.forEach(machines, function(machine){

  // Find the machine starting with '_project_'
  if(_.startsWith(machine, '_project_')){
    // Set machine name in sails.config.treeline
    sails.config.treeline.machine = machine;
  }
});
```

the treeline machine name will be accessible throughout the project as

> sails.config.treeline.machine